# How to automatically execute a method after XML deserialization?

Tags: java, xml, serialization, xml-serialization, xml-deserialization

I have a class containing different graphic elements that I serialized. I use a variable is instantiated in the default constructor. In order to properly put my items, I would have repositioned after the creation of this variable. But during deserialization, the deserialized attributes are not available in the constructor. So I'd just run a method after the object is created and all the attributes are correctly deserialized

How can I do that?

(for serialization and deserialization, I use Java beans XMLEncoder and XMLDecoder)

**EDIT:**

In fact, the class which raises me problem is an attribute of a class container who is she same an attribute of a general class

> Sheet extends JPanel -> JPanel left_container -> **Button extends
>   JButton**

Sheet is the class that I serialize and thus serialize the Button class.

Comment: After you have used the XMLDecoder, you need to call your postDeserialization() method on each object which needs it.

Comment: It's a good idea, but it's not very practical to implement in my case. Indeed, this class is itself contained in another class that is also serialized (I modified my post). 

It obliges me to go through all the intermediate getter methods to reach has this attributes knowing that he can have as value null. Furthermore, it's not the only one has to have the same problem.